# How to create an image in php with justified text

Tags: php, gd

I want to create an image that contains text where the letter spacing is adapted so the text will stretch within the given space. My goal is to split the text in lines of max x millimeters and to justify (increase letter spacing) the text.

Here is an example of the current output:

[image]

This is how it should look:

[image]

Here is my current code:

```
function ImageStringWrap($image, $font, $x, $y, $text, $color, $maxwidth, $textcolor)
{
    $fontwidth = ImageFontWidth($font);
    $fontheight = ImageFontHeight($font);

    if ($maxwidth != NULL) {
        $maxcharsperline = floor($maxwidth / $fontwidth);
        $text = wordwrap($text, $maxcharsperline, "\n", 1);
      }

    $lines = explode("\n", $text);
    while (list($numl, $line) = each($lines)) {
        $fontfile = imageloadfont('app_global/ttf/verdana.ttf');
        ImageString($image, 14, $x, $y, $line, $color);
        #Imagettftext ($image, 14 , 0, $x , $y , $color , $fontfile ,  $line );
        $y += $fontheight;
      }

    $hight = 20*count($lines);
    imageline ($image , 10 , 5 , 290, 5 , $textcolor );
    imageline ($image , 10 , $hight , 290, $hight , $textcolor );
}


header("Content-type: image/png");
$string = urldecode($_GET['text']);
$im     = imagecreate(300, 150);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);


 #imageline ($im , 0 , 10 , 200, 0 , $textcolor );
// Write the string at the top left
#imagestring($im, 11, 10, 10, $string, $textcolor);
ImageStringWrap($im, 11, 10, 10, $string, $textcolor, ImageSX($im), $textcolor);
```

How could I achieve this with php?

With the code from the php.net site mentioned inside the comment section I do get something pretty close, however the text appears blurry:

[image]

Comment: If you take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagettftext.php#113563 there is  a function that I think does what you want

Comment: Thank you. This seems to work, although it is a bit slow as I am creating it on the fly during text input. The bigger problem seems to be the font which is kind of blurry. Will update the question.

Comment: Yes, I can imagine it would be slow - the OP did state it is CPU intensive...

Comment: Thank you. Do you have an idea why the text is so blurry?

Comment: doesn't look blurry to me - the font is quite light though. Other than that - sorry, no - the code you used from php.net is nothing to do with me and I have not studied it at all.